# Wicked PDF. How to remove the margin from the sides of the wicked pdf document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf, wicked-gem

[image]

I'd like to have the table 100% horizontal and the attached image there is space both on the right and on the left

I applied css styles, margin, padding 0 and nothing works for me. I even put width 100% !important to the styles

If someone knows how to remove those spaces from the sides to have the table at 100% width, I would be very grateful.